# Optimization of python code with nested loops

Tags: python, string, list, optimization, nested-loops

This is a hackerrank question and I am kind of a noob here. 5/15 testcases are working but when the string to analyze is too big, the testcase is being terminated due to timeout. Any guidance will be much appreciated.

The question - Both players are given the same string, .
Both players have to make substrings using the letters of the string .
Stuart has to make words starting with consonants.
Kevin has to make words starting with vowels.
If a substring appears x times, it will constitute +x score.
The game ends when both players have made all possible substrings.

```py
def minion_game(string):
    vowels = {'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U'}
    strlen = len(string)
    Stuart, Kevin = 0, 0
    words = set([])
    for i in range(strlen):
        for j in range(i, strlen):
            temp_word = string[i:j + 1]
            temp_word_length = j-i+1
            if temp_word not in words:
                words.add(temp_word)
                no_of_search = strlen - temp_word_length + 1
                score = sum(temp_word == string[x : x + temp_word_length] for x in range(no_of_search))
                if string[i] in vowels:
                    Kevin += score
                else:
                    Stuart += score
    if Stuart > Kevin:
        print('Stuart', Stuart)
    elif Kevin > Stuart:
        print('Kevin', Kevin)
    else:
        print('Draw')
```

Comment: You need to come up with an algorithm that doesn't need so many loops.

Comment: It's hard for us to answer without knowing what this is supposed to do.

Comment: One obvious improvement is to use a set instead of a list for `words`.

Comment: Don't keep recreating `string[i:j + 1]`. Put it in a variable and use that.

Comment: In fact, you do have a variable: `temp_word`. Assign it earlier and use that.

Comment: `len(string[i:j+1])` is just `j-i+1`. No need to create a string to get its length.

Comment: Please explain what this is supposed to do by providing sample input ('string') and expected output along with the reasoning/algorithm. Whilst this may be very inefficient I'm intrigued to know how it times out

Comment: @Barmar I incorporated some of your suggestions can you please relook. Also can you elaborate on how I can use a set for words instead of list? Really appreciate your patience with my naivety.

Comment: @AndyKnight I have added the question, please take a look at it. The testcases that are being timed out consist of a string comrpising of the same character like infinitely. The score in one of such cases was 50005000.

Comment: You can also change `if temp_word in words:` to  `if temp_word not in words:` and you can remove the pass.  You can also change the fot x in range loop into score = sum()

Comment: Infinite strings? You've got me on that one

Comment: @simonT can you elaborate your last point?

Comment: @AndyKnight https://hr-testcases-us-east-1.s3.amazonaws.com/9693/input06.txt?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAR6O7GJNX5DNFO3PV&Expires=1627216591&Signature=PpPDJHengSqfYVt8RfHlDIig7hU%3D&response-content-type=text%2Fplain one of the testcases

Comment: That URL reveals a string of 10,000 'A's. There's nothing infinite about that

Comment: @AndyKnight I meant like very very large only, sorry if my language was not apt. Do you have any solution to the problem tho given the failing test cases are that long?

Comment: This is what I mean by using Sum instead
```score = sum(temp_word == string[x : x + temp_word_length] for x in range(no_of_search)))```

Comment: It would be appreciated that my answer actually solved this for you then to mark it as the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just looked at the question source.

This is probably the shortest way you could do it.

```py
def minion_game(string):
    vowels = ['A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U']
    kevin = 0
    stuart = 0
    for i in range(len(string)):
        if s[i] in vowels:
            kevin += len(s)-i
        else:
            stuart += len(s)-i

    if stuart > kevin:
        print('Stuart '+ str(stuart))
    elif kevin > stuart:
        print('Kevin ' + str(kevin))
    else:
        print('Draw')

s = input()
minion_game(s)
```

This part iterates through each letter in the input string and checks whether it is a vowel.

```py
for i in range(len(string)):
    if s[i] in vowels:
```

HackerRank automatically gives you the below, if you actually check so that's where it is declared.

```py
s = input()
minion_game(s)
```

Comment: okay this worked, but I don't get it. Can you explain the `s[i]` bit? What is s? We don't seem to have declared it.

Comment: s is the input string, if you look at the bottom of hackerrank you'll see  `s = input()`  So this iterates through each letter of the string and checks whether that letter is in vowels. @ApurvaGaurav

Comment: @AndyKnight well, it did. I don't understand it either.

Comment: thanks, I learnt a couple of pretty important things about python through your solution in addition to a very efficient algorithmic approach.